# Get maximum number with combination of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

I have table with columns like AutoID, Number, Name, City, State, Country.

What I wanted is the maximum number entered in the "Number" column with the combination of Name, City, State and Country.

Example:

```
Name     City     State     Country
Smith    NY      NY         USA
John     NY       NY        USA
John     NJ       NY        USA
```

Now smith should get "Number" 1, John 2, and again John(in NJ) 1 as he is the first from NJ.

I can simply put a where clause in query and get the max number + 1. But the problem is that when I have huge amount of data and the number of users increases, my query will be really slow. I am also inserting data in the same table so it will keep on piling.

I hope I have made my self clear.

Vipul Parekh

Comment: What ordering is applied? e.g. Why is `Smith` ahead of `John` in NY?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that this is what you want:

```
Name     City     State     Country    Number
Smith    NY      NY         USA           1
John     NY       NY        USA           2
John     NJ       NY        USA           1
```

This is provided by `row_number()`:

```
select name, city,state, country,
       row_number() over (partition by city, state, country order by (select null)) as Number
from table t;
```

Note that the sequencing of the `Number` within a group is arbitrary, because you don't provide an `id` or `createdat` column.  There is no guarantee that it is in the same order as the table, because SQL tables are inherently unordered.

Comment: hi, sorry for half information. Fetching number is not a problem. Generating it and saving is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger on your table. whenever you insert a row it will count the number of rows and update the latest one with a number with the count + 1.

To get around slowness you can create a index on Name, City, State and Country.

Let me know if you need a sample code or some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
Select Name, 
       City, 
       State, 
       Country,
       Row_Number() over (Partition by City, State, Country ORDER BY Name) AS Number
From table1
) AS T
```

## [WORKING FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65eeb/6)

Answer (score 0):

1)
WITH Optimize_CTE (id, cityid,stateid, countryid)
AS

-- Define the CTE query.
(

```
SELECT id,  cityid,stateid, countryid
FROM Optimize
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
```

)

-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.

SELECT id,
convert(Varchar(255),cityid) as CityId,
convert(Varchar(255),stateid) as StateId,
convert(Varchar(255),countryid) as CountryId 
FROM Optimize_CTE  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1)

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 10, @PageNumber INT = 1

SELECT InvoiceID, CustomerID

FROM dbo.SalesInvoice

ORDER BY InvoiceID

OFFSET (@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage ROWS

FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY

GO